# Ansible dual log format

Tags: linux, logging, ansible, automation

On Ansible config I can set if output log should be human-readable or JSON. Human readable format is displayed task-by-task as it runs and JSON only after playing ends.

It is possible to output to `stdout` human readable format and also create some logfile with the JSON format?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if dual format logging is fully possible in the way your are looking for, but in general regarding

> *It is possible to output to `stdout` human readable format AND also create some logfile with the JSON format?*

and the logging configuration, you may have a look into [Logging Ansible output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html)

> By default Ansible sends output about plays, tasks, and module arguments to your screen (STDOUT) on the control node. If you want to capture Ansible output in a log, you have three options ...

as well you could take advantage from [Callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) and the [`community.general`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html#community-general) plugins.

**Further Q&A**

- [How do I get logs/details of ansible-playbook module executions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18807711/6771046)
- [How to use log_plays to generate a log file for playbook execution in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755132/)
- [How to log in a separate file per playbook in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135954/)